# .htaccess RewriteRule doesn't do anything

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Apologies if an answer for this already exists, I have looked but can't find anyone with the same problem.
mod_rewrite is enabled on my localhost but the rewrite rules I have just don't seem to work.

```
Options -indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /Website

    # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Rewrite index.php
    RewriteRule ^Website([^/]*)/$ /Website/?action=$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

I even used this [mod rewrite generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/) but the generated rules don't work either. Stuff I install locally like Wordpress manage to rewrite the URLs fine, so there must be something wrong with the code I've written

I am out of my depth with this .htaccess stuff so I really appreciate any answers I can get.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a sample URL?

Comment: Is the url you trying to get to a:`Websiteblahblahblah` or b:`Website/blahblahblah`?

Comment: I'm trying to get option b. My URLs currently look like localhost/Website/?action=/register where as I want them to turn into localhost/Website/register/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have set the `RewriteBase` you do not need to redeclare it in the `RewriteRule`

Your rule should read...

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /Website/?action=$1 [L]
```

That'll do it! (this is taking into account that your regex is also fine :p)

EDIT: (explanation)

Once you have set the `RewriteBase` mod_rewrite will only look at everything AFTER the base, so what RewriteRule was absolutely looking for was `/Website/Website([^/]*)/`.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that all makes a lot of sense. However changing the RewriteRule didn't seem to work. It now reads as you have put it but the URLs I am getting still look like:http://localhost/Website/?action=/login

Comment: Ok, after reading your comment above you will need to change the `RewriteRule` so that there is a `/` before the `$1`. You can test the rule by changing the `[L]` to `[L,R]`. This will redirect the browser to the page - but you will be able to see what it is trying to redirect to. When you get the regex right change it back to `[L]`. You might also need to change the `RewriteBase` to `RewriteBase /Website/`

Comment: Thanks again Michael. Now we're getting somewhere. I used [L,R] and found the right regex. Navigating to localhost/Website/register/ now displays the page, but with no CSS. Any ideas? Also I have another question: can you force someone typing the original URL to redirect to the Rewritten URL, e.g. someone who types localhost/Website/?action=register is redirected to localhost/Website/register/
EDIT: Ok, changing the regex slightly Website/register appears everything correctly, but Website/register/ removes CSS.

Comment: You can try something like this to reverse your rule...
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \?action=([^/]*)`
`RewriteRule .* /Website/%1/ [R,L]` (make sure both are on their own lines an that this is above the other rules but below the `RewriteBase`)
However the best way to do it might be in php with the `header()` function. The issue with the CSS is that you have referenced it relatively from the current file (`../`) you need to reference it from root (`/Website/css/styles.css`) you will need to change all links to any other files and pages to reflect this.

Comment: The reason is because the browser now thinks that you are looking at a page inside the `/Website/Register/` "folder". This means that any references to `css/style.css` in `Websites/index.php` now have to take into account that there is another folder level there. (to break it down it is like the browser is requesting `Website/Register/index.php` and `Website/Register/css/style.css` <-- this clearly does not exist) so the CSS is now a folder level lower than it used to be.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help Michael. I fixed the CSS issue and using the header() function sounds more practical than the RewriteCond.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Options -indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /Website

    # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Rewrite index.php
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?action=$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

#### UPDATE:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Website/
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ ?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Similar to Michael's answer you are saying that after RewriteBase you don't need to re-specify the /Website. Unfortunately, removing the preceeding /Website still doesn't work for me.

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: In the same directory as the index.php file.

Comment: ok got it but is it in DOCUMENT_ROOT or DOCUMENT_ROOT/Website?

Comment: I'm using XAMPP, so taking the root to be htdocs, the .htaccess is located at htdocs/Website/.htaccess

Comment: And you're entering `localhost/Website/register` in your browser?

Comment: Yep... Navigating to localhost/Website/register or localhost/Website/login both throw error 404

Comment: ok can you try just the code that is in UPDATE section now in your `htdocs/Website/.htaccess`